# Installing Citrix receiver VIA PowerShell

Tags: powershell, citrix

I'm trying to create a script to install receiver but I'm getting this popup box asking if I'm sure.

```
$InstallFiles = "C:\Users\raw.admin\Documents\CitrixReceiver.exe"
$ArgumentList = '/silent /includeSSON enable_SSON=yes enableprelaunch=true allowaddstore=a STORE0="Kiewit;https://apps.kiewit.com/citrix/kiewit/discovery;on"'
Write-host "Installing Citrix receiver"
Start-Process -FilePath $InstallFiles -ArgumentList $ArgumentList -wait
##Make sure Single Sign is in Provider Order Key

$Path = "HKLM:\system\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\Order"

$ProviderOrder = (Get-ItemProperty -path $path).ProviderOrder
If ($ProviderOrder -NotLike "*PnSson*")

{
    Set-ItemProperty -path $path -Name ProviderOrder -value ($ProviderOrder + ",PnSson")
    $NewProviderOrder = (Get-ItemProperty -path $path).ProviderOrder
    Write-Host Provider Order key now has the following values   $NewProviderOrder
}
Else

{
    Write-Host "PnSson already present in Provider Order"
}

Write-host "Installation Complete"
```

I don't want the user to get prompt to answer the question of yes or no. Can it be done or is it something the user will just have to live with?

Comment: What is the popup box asking you?

Comment: Two Buttons "Run" "Cancel"

Comment: That is all that's on the popup box? There is no other text? Are you sure it's from the Citrix installer? I don't think I've ever seen that popup from the Citrix installer.

Comment: Its a Windows Box that pops up and ask you to confirm the install or cancel.

Comment: I think this is the longest I've gone with no answers.

Comment: Is this the UAC prompt that pops up?

Comment: No. Its the security prompt that comes up that says Run or Cancel.

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot?

Comment: I figured it out. Under the properties of the .exe I selected unblock.